# Netbeans and Boost libraries in OSX

Tags: c++, regex, macos, boost, netbeans

So far I have downloaded the boost libraries using brew and found their location and copied them to my home folder.

I've tried to follow closely how to add these libraries from windows tutorials, but I seem to be missing something. Upon compiling this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main() {
    string s = "This is my simple sample text, really.";
    regex re(",|:|-|\s+");
    sregex_token_iterator my_iter(s.begin( ), s.end( ), re, -1);
    sregex_token_iterator my_end;
    while (my_iter != my_end)
        cout << *my_iter++ << 'n';
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I simply get an error stating that `#include <boost/regex.hpp> file not found`

Using

- **Netbeans 8.0.1**
- **Mac OS 10.9.5**

Most tutorials show how to set up using cygwin, which doesn't apply to me since I'm on windows and there are no helpful or easy to follow tutorials for Mac OS.

Please and Thank you for any help on this matter.

Comment: Why would you copy Boost to your home directory?  Just add the include path and library path for it in your NetBeans project settings.

Comment: You're talking about project properties>linker>libraries. Right?

Comment: because that hasn't worked, when they were linked from their original destination nor when i copied them to my home folder. I copied them to my home folder thinking it might have been an issue with it locating the files.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error i have figured it out!

So in Netbeans 8.0.1 what you want to do to set up for regex is:

Under `Netbeans>Preferences select the C/C++ tab`, then in this window tap on `"Code Assistance"` then `"C++ Compiler"`

In the `"Include Directories"` you are going to add the location where you saved your boost libraries and header files, on my machine it install to 
    `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0`
yours may be different.

Once you've done that, hit `"Apply"` and you can close this window.

I then used the code from my original post to create a new c++ project.

Once you can compile a "Hello World" go ahead and replace your code with the once from my original post.

On the left hand side (default) where your project folder is, right-click the folder and select `"Properties"`. You should then get this window. Navigate to `"C++ Compiler"` under the `"Build"` option.

Remember how we located the folder where both the include files and library files? Do the same in the `"Include Directories"` section, except this time you will select the folder which contains the .hpp files. In my case it was `"/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0/include"`
Hit `"Apply"`.

So that takes care of out header files. Now lets do the library files!

Once that is done, navigate to the `"Linker"` option within the same option window. We are/were in.

Under the `"Addition Library Directories"` Locate the folder that contains your dynamic and static libraries. These filetypes should end in `.a or .dylib.`
Mine were located in `"/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0/lib"`

Now all you have to do is select the `"Libraries" and the "..."` on the right which will give you a new window.

Here you will select `"Add Library File"` and add the following...

they should be labelled:

`"libboost_program_options-mt.dylib"

"libboost_regex-mt.dylib"`

Once this is done, build and run and your result when using the code above should be:
`"Thin in my nimple nample textn really.n"`

Hope this help anyone else!